# WSO2 CEP doesn't logging input events

Tags: logging, wso2, wso2-cep

I want to check how long is my event processing in CEP (v.3.1.0). I change `org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adaptor.jms.internal.util.JMSMessageListener` to `DEBUG/TRACE` level and the same with `org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adaptor.jms.internal.util.JMSMessageSender`.

In console I have only output adapter logs. Maybe someone knows how to fix it or some workaround?

EDIT 02.02.2015

This adapters has to be initialized (the first send event or the first receive event), then in "Logging" option, can change them log level.

Kacu

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the WSO2 CEP Event tracing capability [1]. You can enable tracing for a particular artifact (e.g. JMSInputAdaptor) and then you can view the logged messages using the Monitor -> Event Tracer in the management console. Additionally, you can view the logged trace messages in /repository/logs/wso2-cep-trace.log

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP310/CEP+Event+Tracer